# Script to create several groups in site collection - CSOM / Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365

I have the script below to create a group on a site collection in sharepoint online.

I would like to know how can I change it in order to create several groups in the same site collection?

Many thanks in advance

```
$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread" 

#Definition of the function that allows to create a SharePoint Group in a SharePoint Online Site function 

Create-SPOGroup { param ($sSiteColUrl,$sUsername,$sPassword,$sGroupToCreate,$sGroupToCreateDescription) try { 

Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor Green 

Write-Host "Creating SharePoint Group $sGroupToCreate in $sSiteColUrl" -foregroundcolor Green 

Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor Green 

#Adding the Client OM Assemblies 

Add-Type -Path "C:\CSOMDLL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 

Add-Type -Path "C:\CSOMDLL\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 

#SPO Client Object Model Context 

$spoCtx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($sSiteColUrl) $spoCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($sUsername, $sPassword) $spoCtx.Credentials = $spoCredentials 

#Root Web Site 

$spoRootWebSite = $spoCtx.Web #Object for creating a new SPO Group $spoGroupCreationInfo=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.GroupCreationInformation $spoGroupCreationInfo.Title=$sGroupToCreate $spoGroup=$spoRootWebSite.SiteGroups.Add($spoGroupCreationInfo) $spoCtx.ExecuteQuery() 

Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor Green 

Write-Host "SharePoint Group $sGroupToCreate in $sSiteColUrl created succesfully!!" -foregroundcolor Green 

Write-Host "----------------------------------------------------------------------------" -foregroundcolor Green $spoCtx.Dispose() } catch [System.Exception] { 

write-host -f red $_.Exception.ToString() } } 

#Required Parameters 
$sSiteColUrl = "sitecol" 
$sUsername = "user" 

#$sPassword = Read-Host -Prompt "pass" -AsSecureString 
$sPassword=convertto-securestring "pass" -asplaintext -force $sGroupToCreate="Sharepointgroup3" 

Create-SPOGroup -sSiteColUrl $sSiteColUrl -sUsername $sUsername -sPassword $sPassword -sGroupToCreate $sGroupToCreate
```

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of code will help you, but it is in CSOM.

```
 public string CreateGroup(ClientContext clientContext, string title, string description)
    {

        clientContext.RequestTimeout = -1;
        string strGroupNameAlrdyExst = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            //  Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group sgroup = GetGroupDetail(title, slogin);
            Site site = clientContext.Site;
            Web web = clientContext.Web;
            GroupCollection grupcoll = web.SiteGroups;

            clientContext.Load(grupcoll, grups => grups.Include(grup => grup.Title).Where(grup => grup.Title == title));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            //create the group
            if (grupcoll.Count > 0)
            {
                strGroupNameAlrdyExst = title;
            }
            else
            {                  
                GroupCreationInformation grp = new GroupCreationInformation();
                grp.Title = title;
                grp.Description = description;

                //add it to the list of site groups
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Group newgrp = clientContext.Web.SiteGroups.Add(grp);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            }
            return strGroupNameAlrdyExst;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return strGroupNameAlrdyExst;
        }

    }
```

Run it in for loop for creating multiple.

Comment: I need it in CSOM.. could you please guys help?

Comment: Yeah it is in CSOM

Comment: check updated code